# How to remove the same part in multiple file name using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove same part in multiple file names using Python but the loop is not getting iterated. It is only entering the path but it is not removing the same part from file names.

```
import os

for root_dir,cur_dir,file_name in os.walk("D:\Python\Scripts"):
    if "new_" in file_name:
    old_name=file_name
    new_name=file_name.replace("new_","")
    os.rename(old_name,new_name)
```

There are sub folders inside folders where the file name needs to be replaced so I have used root_dir,cur_dir in os.walk function.

```
Input file Names in directory:
New_File1.xlsx
New_Data1.xlsx
New_Task1.xlsx

Output file names should be:
File1.xlsx
Data1.xlsx
Task1.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would try to get the formatting right

```py
import os

for root_dir,cur_dir,file_name in os.walk("D:\Python\Scripts"):
    if "new_" in file_name:
        old_name=file_name
        new_name=file_name.replace("new_","")
        os.rename(old_name,new_name)
```

Furthermore, your code is looking for `new_`. As string comparisons are case sensitive, the comparison of `new_` to `New_` will return false.

```py
import re

old_value = "New_File"
insensitive_new = re.compile(re.escape('new_'), re.IGNORECASE)
new_value = insensitive_new.sub("", old_value)
print(new_value)
```

So your code should look something along these lines:

```py
import os
insensitive_new = re.compile(re.escape('new_'), re.IGNORECASE)

for root_dir,cur_dir,file_name in os.walk("D:\Python\Scripts"):
    if "new_" in file_name.lower(): # Converted file_name to lower case for comparison
        new_name=insensitive_new.sub("", file_name) # Replacing new_ with nothing, ignoring case
        os.rename(file_name, new_name)
```

**UPDATE**

I've only noticed now how we're iterating :)

```
import os
import re

insensitive_new = re.compile(re.escape('new_'), re.IGNORECASE)

for root_dir, cur_dir, file_names in os.walk("D:\Python\Scripts"):
    # Iterate through filenames
    for file_name in file_names:
        # Converted file_name to lower case for comparison
        if "new_" in file_name.lower():
            # Replacing new_ with nothing, ignoring case
            new_name = insensitive_new.sub("", file_name) 

            # Renaming file at the path
            os.rename(os.path.join(root_dir, file_name), os.path.join(root_dir, new_name))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have added lower case comparison now. I am getting same output. It is not changing the file name in that given particular path.

Comment: Hopefully, update resolves it